# How do I swap an MFC CString?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, swap, cstring, copy-and-swap

OK, so I'm all sold on the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) and I think I mostly know how to implement it.

However, or codebase uses [MFC's CString class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) as string and this ain't gonna change.

Since `swap` must (should???) be nothrow, I *cannot* do

```
std::swap(this->my_cstring, rhs.my_cstring);
```

since that will create a temporary CString object which may throw. (Plus its inefficient.)

So where I'm left? Should I add a try-catch? Should I actually allow this (well, extremely rare) out of memory condition to raise an exception and make swap fail?

Looking at CStrings implementation, it doesn't seem there's a member or function that allows for swapping ...

Comment: I can't see a reason to code defensively for out-of-memory. Dealing with it in your CString swap just means it will pop up somewhere else, right?

Comment: @Aidan: What do you mean by "dealing with it". You simply cannot swap a `CString` in a 100% exception save manner.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if the only thing your try/catch around the swap could encounter is out-of-memory, there should not be a try/catch because out-of-memory will just crash you elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-Answer:

After looking into CString more closely, it appears that due to the fact the CString is a *reference counted* string implementation, swapping it via std::swap is actually "99%" exception safe because all that happens is some reference count increments and decrements.

It's only "99%" safe, as when the CString object `IsLocked`, it will always do a copy.

Comment: If not IsLocked *and* the StringMgrs are the same, then `CSimpleStringT::CloneData(CStringData *)` simply increases the reference count.

Comment: @Daniel - eah, I mentioned IsLocked (which should be rare anyway). I didn't even check anything about StringMgrs.